# Notepad++ regular expression issue with non matching patterns

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to modify lines that do not contain one pattern but do contain another pattern:

```
Table: tablename         page.
Table: xxcellname
```

Whenever the word "Table" appears at the start of a line and the word "page" does NOT appear on the line, I want to replace "Table: " with white space.
so that in the above example

```
Table: xxcellname
```

becomes

```
         cellname
```

and

```
Table: tablename         page.
```

Stays the same

I've tried using:

Replace    `(^Table :)^((!?.*Page).)*$`
with       `\2`

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating your regex. Just use a negative lookahead and replace with some spaces: `^Table:(?!.*page)`. Note: `.` doesn't match a newline by default

Comment: What is the pattern for the `xx` in `Table: xxcellname` because if there isn't a pattern for this will be difficult

Comment: To expand on what @JorgeCampos asks, where does the `xx` go when converting `Table: xxcellname` to `cellname`? If this is a mistake in the question then please correct it.

Comment: Or, why did "xx" get removed? Was that deliberate? Does "x" represent "any character" or a literal "x"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(?m)^Table:((?:(?!page).)*)$
```

and replace with 6 spaces and the first capture group:

```
      \1
```

When applied to the input:

```
Table: tablename         page.
Table: xxcellname 
Table: tablename         page.
Table: xxcellname 
Table: tablename         page.
Table: xxcellname
```

it will provide the following output:

```
Table: tablename         page.
       xxcellname 
Table: tablename         page.
       xxcellname 
Table: tablename         page.
       xxcellname
```